# Units and ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Suppose $A$ is principal ideal. For $x\in A$

Prove that
$$ x \  \ is \ \ unit \longleftrightarrow (x)=A=(1)$$
I don't know where to start. Please help.

Comment: *sigh* Where is the duplicate for this? I can only find https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1488831/29335 but it seems like there should be better ones...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

- An element $x\in A$ is a unit by definition means that there is some element $y\in A$ such that $xy=1_A$.
- The ideal $(x)$ equals $A$ if and only if it contains every element of $A$, in particular it contains $1_A$.
- $(x)=\{xy\mid y\in A\}$.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: As by definition of unit $xy=1_A$ for $y\in A $

which gives $(x)=\{xy\mid y\in A\} =1_A=(1) \  \rightarrow \  (x)=A=(1) $

Can we do this?

Comment: Yes, that is what I tried to hint at. :-)

Comment: for $\leftarrow$ if we suppose that $(x)=A=(1)$ then $(x)=\{xy\mid y\in A\} =1_A=(1)$ $\ \ \ \ \rightarrow xy=1_A$ so $x$ is unit.
is it correct?

Comment: I think this is correct, and forms a complete proof. :-)

Comment: Thank you.......

Answer (score 0):

$\rightarrow$

Suppose that x is a unit. So by definition $xy=1_A$ for some $y\in A.$

Now $(x)=\{xy\mid y\in A\} =1_A=(1)$ $\ \ \rightarrow (x)=A=(1)$

$\leftarrow$

if we suppose that $(x)=A=(1)$ then $(x)=\{xy\mid y\in A\} =1_A=(1)$ $\ \ \ \ \rightarrow xy=1_A$ so $x$ is unit.